# ADB pushing only part of a file when using Node

Tags: android, node.js, adb, electron

I'm working on a program made in Electron which installs an apk to a connected Android device using the [Android SDK Platform Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html). I'm using the Node `child-process` module to execute commands within the JavaScript code.

In this particular case, I'm using the following command: `adb.exe install app.apk`

Whenever I use this command on my own command line it works perfectly, and the app is installed correctly. However, when the program executes the command, I get the following output:

```
[  0%] /data/local/tmp/app.apk
[  1%] /data/local/tmp/app.apk
[  1%] /data/local/tmp/app.apk
[  2%] /data/local/tmp/app.apk
[...]
[ 41%] /data/local/tmp/app.apk
[ 42%] /data/local/tmp/app.apk
[ 42%] /data/local/tmp/app.apk
C:\Users\user\Desktop\app\app.apk: 1 file pushed. 3.0 MB/s (4456448 bytes in 1.430s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/app.apk

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
```

The file is about 10mb and it only pushes about 4.5mb before trying to install the app, thus giving the INVALID_APK error.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: are you using `child_process.execSync()` ?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano No, I'm using child-process